# Weighted rand function in MS Excel according to rank number

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Long story short I need to make a weighted rand function in Microsoft excel
I have a ranked list of 26 people and need the rand to have a raised chance of giving the letter E to those lower (As in first second third) on the ranked list, those in the middle need a higher chance of receiving the letter s and those at the end of the list (E.g. 24, 25 and 26) to have a higher chance of getting the letter r
My table is set out in 2 columns. column A is empty while column b has the rank numbers.
Any help or guidance is much apreciated

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Any possibility that you give some examples of what can be the input and what should be the output for these input and why those output should be like that?

Comment: Column one: Blank rows, Colum 2: Numbers from 1-26 I have three letters i need the rand function to chose from; E, S And R I need the rand function to increase the chance of the letter E occuring the higher the number next to it is, likewise with the other 2 letters. (S For 'middle' numbers' and R for 'high' numbers)

Comment: Sorry for all the edits

Comment: That's fine, fut do you have any _actual_ values? Which number(s) for example should get `R`, which one(s) should get `E`? What should be the probability of having E on the number 26? And what about 10?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking that I could divide the number in Column b by 26 and then multiply it by 100 and that was there chance of getting the letter R then there chance of getting S would be twice that (Value In Column B/26*100) and the chance of getting a E would be the rest (If you know what I mean) Sorry for the confusion, and I do appreciate your help

Comment: By that, it means that 26 will always be R, while 1 has a 3.84% chance of getting R. Additionally, all numbers 9 and above is guaranteed to get either R or S based on the details you provided. Are those okay?